# List all the rows that match a string in a column

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-query

My ultimate goal:

[image]

I want to look in a specific column to match a specific string and list all the rows that match the string in the column.

Note: I am doing a personal MS Excel on my computer but I'm also doing it in Google Sheets - to share with partners. I am not sure if the formulas are the same for both but as long as either works I'll be happy. The two spreadsheets have different listings but I'm still looking to apply it to both somehow. So I suppose this question is for Google Sheets but if anyone knows how to do it for Excel, or both, please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Google Spreadsheets please enter in G11:

```
=query(A:D,"select A,B,C where D=1")
```

Change the last `1` to `2` for L11 ... and so forth.

To exclude the labels:

```
=query(A:D,"select A,B,C where D=1 label A '', B '', C '' ")
```

Or, much neater!, courtesy @Mogsdad:

> You can exclude the headers with the headers parameter;
>       `=query(A:D,"select A,B,C where D=1", FALSE)`

Comment: that works but the only problem im having with that in google docs is that it is displaying Row 1. so i changed A:D to A2:D and that seems to be working. thank you sooooo much! 

i also remember you helped me in excel before. you must be an expert :)

Comment: hmm for the most part its working but the first row is being displayed even tho its not marked. this is only happening in 2 out of 9 sheets that it is displaying the first rows. any ideas?

Comment: no not the labels but A2, B2, C2 even tho D doesnt =1 but it still picks up the rest, just this extra A2. A2 is a part of the list of data so i cant exclude it from the range...

Comment: my mistake i copied your edit after my post about copying A2 even tho its not selected. from my first reply i had added A2:D but i reverted it back to A:D which now works with the label exclusion. all is good!!! thank you so much!

Comment: You can exclude the headers with the `headers` parameter; `=query(A:D,"select A,B,C where D=1", FALSE)`.

Comment: offtopic but is there a way to include a range in "where"? i cant do D<=2 so it only brings up out 2 or 1 because even tho they are blank it still counts them as 0 which is the whole list. just experimenting with having a query to select where D=1or2 and the other D=3-4 and so on.